# "Sorted List Output" Powershell Script

Tags: powershell

How can I format the output in a PowerShell script from this command? When I just type it in the console it sorts nicely, but in the script it just throw all in one row.

```
$diskpartitions = Get-Partition |Select PartitionNumber, DriveLetter, Size, DiskId | Sort-Object DiskId
    Write-Host $diskpartitions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Write-Host` converts any input given to it into the form of a string.  A string has to take a nicely formatted PowerShell object and convert it into, well, a string.

You should use `Write-Output` instead, which will render your object as you have it.

```
PS>Write-output $diskpartitions

PartitionNumber DriveLetter          Size DiskId
--------------- -----------          ---- ------
              1                 16777216 \\?\scsi#disk&ven_nvme&prod_samsung_ssd_960#5&17cb1da0&0&000000#{53f56307-b6…
              2           C  499537713664 \\?\scsi#disk&ven_nvme&prod_samsung_ssd_960#5&17cb1da0&0&000000#{53f56307-b6…
              3                550502400 \\?\scsi#disk&ven_nvme&prod_samsung_ssd_960#5&17cb1da0&0&000000#{53f56307-b6…
              1                134217728 \\?\scsi#disk&ven_nvme&prod_samsung_ssd_960#7&1a97d747&0&000000#{53f56307-b6…
              2           V  499971522560 \\?\scsi#disk&ven_nvme&prod_samsung_ssd_960#7&1a97d747&0&000000#{53f56307-b6…
              1           W 1000202043392 \\?\scsi#disk&ven_samsung&prod_hd103sj#5&1bc941f&0&070000#{53f56307-b6bf-11d…
              1                471859200 \\?\scsi#disk&ven_samsung&prod_ssd_850_pro_256g#5&1bc941f&0&010000#{53f56307…
              2                103809024 \\?\scsi#disk&ven_samsung&prod_ssd_850_pro_256g#5&1bc941f&0&010000#{53f56307…
              3                 16777216 \\?\scsi#disk&ven_samsung&prod_ssd_850_pro_256g#5&1bc941f&0&010000#{53f56307…
              4           D  255466668032 \\?\scsi#disk&ven_samsung&prod_ssd_850_pro_256g#5&1bc941f&0&010000#{53f56307…
              1           G 1000202043392 \\?\scsi#disk&ven_samsung&prod_ssd_860_evo_1tb#5&1bc941f&0&060000#{53f56307-…
              1                134217728 \\?\scsi#disk&ven_seagate&prod_backup+_hub_bk#8&2a5cdee5&0&000000#{53f56307-…
              2           H 6001039245312 \\?\scsi#disk&ven_seagate&prod_backup+_hub_bk#8&2a5cdee5&0&000000#{53f56307-…
```

#### Fun protip

Every line of PowerShell code has an implicit `Write-Output` call at the end.  You can just echo out the contents of a variable by having the variable name by itself on a line, as an easy alternative.

```
PS> $diskpartitions

PartitionNumber DriveLetter          Size DiskId
--------------- -----------          ---- ------
              1                 16777216 \\?\scsi#disk&ven_nvme&prod_sa
#...same content as before
```

Comment: thank you very much mate <3 greetings from germany!